# fprintf Command in Gauss-Seidel MATLAB Code

Tags: matlab, printf

I have the following MATLAB code for solving a system of equation using the Gauss-Seidel Method. I'm wondering what the percentages mean in the fprintf command?

`k = 1; x1 = 0; x2 = 0; x3 = 0;

disp(‘ k x1 x2 x3’)

fprintf(‘ %2.0f %-8.5f %-8.5f %-8.5f \n’, k, x1, x2, x3)

for k = 2:4

x1 = (17 - x2 + 2*x3)/20;

x2 = (-18 - 3*x1 + x3)/20;

x3 = (25 - 2*x1 + 3*x2)/20;

fprintf(‘ %2.0f %-8.5f %-8.5f %-8.5f \n’, k, x1, x2, x3)

end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an fprintf statement that you want to insert a variable into, you use a **format operator** to indicate to Matlab what variable type you want to format as a string. The format operator is formed by a percent sign (%), an optional value for the output length (number), and a letter of the type (f for float, in your example).

In summary, the percent sign is part of the format operator for inserting variables into strings.

This link provides more information on fprintf and the various operators that you can use: [https://users.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/fprintf.html](https://users.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/fprintf.html)